# When does Dockerfile executes, and why groupadd and usereadd not working

Tags: docker

**I have two questions:**

1. Dockerfile has two command, add group and user, both named www, but didn't create.
2. How to stop the container created by docker-compose up -d.

---

I followed this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git mylaravel9
```

Edit docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile, then

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The browser "http://localhost" shows, but with an error, a log file with permission problem. This was solved, but not really solved.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:8.1.4-fpm
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**The first question:**

When first time do

```
docker-compose up -d
```

It pulls things, and run the commands in Dockerfile. There is a problem, which is also solved

```
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl]: exit code: 1
```

A post says the "mbstring" needs to be taken off. Ok, the Dockerfile really used. But there are two commands not working

```
# Add user for laravel application  
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www  
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
```

Because

```
docker exec -it app bash
```

and in the app container's shell

```
cd /var/www  
ls -l
```

I saw the group and owner is number 1000, not www. Then

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

The user and group of "www" doesn't exist! Why?
I manually add the www group and user, and do chmod, the problem of log file permission is solved. But why www doesnt exist? The add commands are in the Dockerfile.

**The second question**
Exit the app shell, back to Ubuntu

```
docker ps
```

Shows three conatiners: php, nginx, mysql. But in docker interface(Windows 11), there is a container named by the folder mylaravel9.

```
docker stop mylaravel9
```

It says:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: mylaravel9
```

So I can only stop the whole thing in the docker UI? If I want to use command, I have to stop the three containers? Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two significant problems in the setup you show.

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./:/var/www
```

In the Dockerfile, you `COPY --chown` content to a different user, but then this `volumes:` mount hides everything the image setup does in the `/var/www` directory and replaces it with content from the host.  Inside the container you'll see the host's numeric user ID and the possibly-unrelated code from the host.  I'd recommend just deleting this line.

```yaml
build: .
image: php:8.1.4-fpm
```

This combination tells Compose to build your application from its Dockerfile, then to label the result as the original `php:8.1.4-fpm` image.  When you re-run `docker-compose build` it will start from the thing labeled as `php:8.1.4-fpm`, which means you're repeatedly reinstalling your application on top of itself.

Delete the `image:` line if you're not planning to push the built image to a registry (and if you are, use the name and tag for the built image, not the base image).  `docker pull php:8.1.4-fpm` manually to make sure you have a "good" copy of this base image.

In the context of a Compose project, you don't usually need to use basic `docker` commands; there are `docker-compose` wrappers for most operations.  If you want to update your application and restart its container it should be enough to

```sh
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

will will recreate the changed `app` container but leave the others alone.    If you do need to stop an individual container for some reason ("stopped" is a somewhat unusual state) then [`docker-compose stop`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/) can do it.

Comment: I dont quite understand. The group and user still not created?

Comment: If you `docker-compose run --rm app cat /etc/passwd` you should see the user exists.  But the files don't have that owner because the `volumes:` mount hides everything the Dockerfile does and replaces it with host files with host-user ownership.

Comment: docker-compose.yml, delete the "image:php" line, and build. Still some errors, it's because some directives different since php 7.4, like --with-freetype-dir=/usr change to --with-freetype – 

Then build again, this time, www really exists. Amazing. But in the previous try, www really doesnt' exist. I did the cat /etc/passwd. volumes only replace files, won't affect/influence the system user and group, isn't it? Any, now it does exist. Thank you.